# How to Pipe Output to a File When Running as a Systemd Service?

Tags: linux, stdout, fedora, systemd, stderr

I'm having trouble piping the STDOUT & STDERR to a file when running a program as a systemd service. I've tried adding the following to the `.service` file:

```
ExecStart=/apppath/appname > /filepath/filename 2>&1
```

But this doesn't work. The output is ending up in /var/log/messages and is viewable using journalctl but I'd like a separate file.

I've also tried setting `StdOutput=tty` but can't find a way of redirecting this to a file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 51):

[`systemd.service(5)`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=) says:

> ExecStart=
>
> Commands with their arguments that are executed when this service is started.

So, `systemd` runs your `/apppath/appname` with args `>`, `/filepath/filename`, `2>&1`

Try:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/apppath/appname > /filepath/filename 2>&1'
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped but the underlying problem I was having turned out to be with SELinux silently blocking writes to the logging folder I was trying to use.

Comment: Some might want to replace the first > with >> to append to the log file.

Comment: To note - this will spawn two processes, one for the shell wrapper and one for appname. To kill both processes with 'systemctl stop appname', use pkill in ExecStop.

    ExecStop=/bin/pkill -TERM -P $MAILPID

Comment: @siliconrockstar see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillMode=

Comment: ^ Yeah I just learned that, you can set KillMode=control-group to kill all the processes, without having to kill all processes in ExecStop or ExecReload.

Comment: You can use `exec` to replace shell with the target process. By using this, you will get rid of need for killing 2 procs with KillMode or whatever.  

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/local/bin/service &>> /var/log/service.log'`

Comment: This problem is just another reason why i loathe `systemd`.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh -c "/apppath/appname > /filepath/filename 2>&1"
```

ExecStart requires the first argument to be a binary (no exceptions), and doesn't allow pipes or redirection. Therefore, use ExecStart to start a shell within which you can do all the fancy things required.