# Piping systemd output into a file

Tags: logging, systemd, piping

I am attempting to pipe the output of my command in systemd to a file using >>
like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968506/how-to-pipe-output-to-a-file-when-running-as-a-systemd-service) question

Unfortunately the result I get back makes it out as if the original command i'm running is using >> as a switch and doesn't recognise it.

I did the same thing using upstart previously but did not run into this error :(

This is my systemd.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ss13_server
[Service]
User=ss13
WorkingDirectory=/home/ss13/ss13
ExecStart=/usr/local/byond/bin/DreamDaemon /home/ss13/ss13/baystation12.dmb 25565 -trusted >> /home/ss13/ss13-log
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=90s
```

The result I get is:

`Dream Daemon: invalid option '>>'`

Normally I'd assume there's something about DreamDaemon that is incompatible with >> but as I said I have used this method successfully in the past; it will also work If I run the command manually.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: In the future, `systemd` questions are better suited for [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com), as StackOverflow is focused on programming questions.

Comment: That doesn't work, because `>>` is a shell script option. Systemd runs the command directly without any shell. But you can of course do something like `ExecStart=bash "/mycommand >>myfile"`.

Comment: @Marki555: we need absolute paths, so it should be `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "<insert_command_here>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your command line in a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/byond/bin/DreamDaemon /home/ss13/ss13/baystation12.dmb 25565 -trusted >> /home/ss13/ss13-log
```

Then have `ExecStart=` reference that file.

Comment: Ah well, it'll do. Thanks!